# How to setup ChangeNotifier for loading locale files

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, future, provider, consumer

I am new to flutter.

I am building a multi language app.

Before app start it needs to load current locale file.
Then every time user changes the locale it needs to load the new file.

At least in theory, I think this can be done using "ChangeNotifierProvider" , ProxyProvider or something similar.

So I have AppLanguage class load the correct locale file based on language code

```
class AppLanguage extends ChangeNotifier {

  String _appLocale = 'en';
  Map<String, String> _localizedStrings;

  Map<String, String> get localeData => this._localizedStrings;

  Future<bool> getLocaleData() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.getString('language_code') == null) {
      _appLocale = 'en';
      await prefs.setString('language_code', _appLocale);
    } else {
      _appLocale = prefs.getString('language_code');
    }
    String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('i18n/$_appLocale.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
    _localizedStrings = jsonMap.map((key, value) {
      return MapEntry(key, value.toString());
    });
    return true;
  }

  Future<void> changeLanguage(String locale) async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _appLocale = locale;
    await prefs.setString('language_code', locale);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

getLocaleData() function read the data and changeLanguage change current locale and fires notifyListeners

```
class Translator {

  final Map<String, String> localizedStrings;

  Translator(this.localizedStrings);

  String translate(String key) {
    return localizedStrings[key];
  }
}
```

the Widgets will use translator class to get the correct translations.

The problem I have is, how to wire this up in main. I am stuck at how to setup the providers.

```
void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  AppLanguage appLanguage = AppLanguage();
  await appLanguage.getLocaleData();
  runApp(MyApp(appLanguage: appLanguage));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final AppLanguage appLanguage;
  MyApp({this.appLanguage});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MultiProvider(


      providers: [
        ProxyProvider<AppLanguage, Translator>(
          update: (context, appLanguage, trans) =>
              Translator(appLanguage.localeData),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Language Demo',
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hello'),
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone kindly provide some help to wire this up?
Or maybe provide a better way of doing this?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62433208/flutter-how-to-detect-device-language/62434238#62434238, MaterialApp has a parameter localizationsDelegates where you can create your own delegate to update when the device language change

Comment: I tried this. For some reason it does not work with Japanese language.
The example here;
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-internationalization-the-easy-way-using-provider-and-json-c47caa4212b2
Work perfectly for Arabic language but not for Japanese

Comment: Did you add in the supported languages Locale('ja', '')? It seems the flutter localization has Japanese tag included so I find it weird it doesn't work https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations-library.html

Comment: Yes I did.
Seems like a simple change to get it working. But it does not.
Just by changing to jp getting error 

"This application's locale, jp, is not supported by all of its localization delegates"
Maybe there is additional setup is required to get it working.

Comment: I add question for that also
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62540699/flutter-internationalization-for-japanese-failed

Comment: I got the japanese language working. Mistake was, i was using jp not ja. Anyway I am interested in how to get this method working also? Any idea how to wire this up?

Answer (score 1):

A few things, ProxyProvider (or any type of ProxyProvider, ChangeNotifierProxyProvider, etc.) updates its value when the provider it depends on changes too, but you created the AppLanguage in main, without an inject dependency, just like a simple class (it's not really provided in the context) so it would be easier to just use a ChangeNotifierProvider in this case.

There is a parameter called window.locale that return the language the device it's using at that time, at the start of the app you can use it to know the language of the device if you're don't have it the sharedPreference the first time. Advante of this it's that in your example if there is not preference saved it will use the default 'en' for English, but you also support japanase, so if someone has its device in japanese and download your app for the first time it would be nice to use japanese since the beginning.

```
Future<Locale> _getLocaleData() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String languageCode = prefs.getString('language_code');
    if (languageCode  == null) {
      return window.locale;
    } else {
      return Locale(languageCode);
    }
}

void main() async {
  Locale locale = await _getLocaleData();
  runApp(MyApp(
    appLanguage: locale,
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Locale language;

  MyApp({this.language});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<AppLanguage>(
      builder: (_) => AppLanguage(language),
      child: Consumer<AppLanguage>(builder: (context, model, _) {
        return MaterialApp(
          locale: model.appLocal,
          supportedLocales: [
            Locale('en', 'US'),
            Locale('ja', ''),
          ],
          localizationsDelegates: [
            AppLocalizations.delegate, //create your AppLocalizations just like the article you shared
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          home: MyWidget(),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

class AppLanguage extends ChangeNotifier {

  AppLanguage(Locale locale) : _appLocale = locale;
  
  Locale _appLocale;
  Locale get appLocal => _appLocale;

  Future<void> changeLanguage(String locale) async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _appLocale = Locale(locale);
    await prefs.setString('language_code', locale);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```