# Flutter internationalization for Japanese failed

Tags: flutter, internationalization, locale

I am new to flutter.
I want to get the support for Japanese language for the application.
I followed the example listed here;
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-internationalization-the-easy-way-using-provider-and-json-c47caa4212b2

It works perfectly for Arabic language listed there, but when i try the same for Japanese.
It does not work.

Only thing I did was modify to include 'jp' locale

```
return MaterialApp(
          locale: model.appLocal,
          supportedLocales: [
            Locale('en', 'US'),
            Locale('jp', 'JP'),
          ],
          localizationsDelegates: [
            AppLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          home: AppLang(),
        );
```

...

```
@override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    // Include all of your supported language codes here
    return ['en', 'jp'].contains(locale.languageCode);
  }
```

getting error

```
I/flutter (20037): Warning: This application's locale, jp, is not supported by all of its
I/flutter (20037): localization delegates.
I/flutter (20037): > A MaterialLocalizations delegate that supports the jp locale was not found.
I/flutter (20037): See https://flutter.dev/tutorials/internationalization/ for more
I/flutter (20037): information about configuring an app's locale, supportedLocales,
I/flutter (20037): and localizationsDelegates parameters.
```

I found information that state there is advance locale support
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization
But no information no how to do it.

Can anyone provide some help on this?

Comment: Change it to Locale('ja', ''),

Comment: @EdwynZN it worked!! Thanks

Comment: Check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_localizations/GlobalMaterialLocalizations-class.html for all the supported languages codes, if you want to implement your own then you must create your own class for AppLocalizations.delegate, GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate and GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate all with the same codes to avoid this problem

Comment: I want to create support for unsupported language. I have followed the flutter documentation to the letter and yet my local language support - Kinyarwanda is not loading at all.

Comment: GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate, was missing for me and was the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need use ja_JA here you can get more information

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations-library.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Flutter localization supports language codes registered in [IANA Language Subtag Registry](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Locale/languageCode.html). For Japanese, the code should be `ja` for the language type.